# Content disappearing in Safari on webpage? It works in firefox and chrome

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, safari

I visited the following website, [youvisit](http://youvisit.com), in safari browser, but the content keeps on disappearing and reappearing when I scroll up and down. I wanted to ask what can be causing this issue. It's most likely the CSS, but I researched a lot but I haven't found any solutions to this issue. The website works correctly in firefox and chrome.

Comment: what's your os? looks fine to me on a mac. also this is probably a question you should be bringing to their attention.

Comment: Doesn't work for me either.  Windows 10, Safari 5.1.7.  The landing page with moving elements is not showing in Safari.  Seems to be fine in the other mainstream browser.  I was wondering if it had to do with javascript on/off, but that is not the case anyway.

Comment: I think it works if you add -webkit-transform: transform3D(0,0,0);. This will force to render the content using the GPU hardware.